# RDP/NLA/CAC Smartcard authentication fails

Tags: remote-desktop, smartcard

I am able to RDP into VMs through username and password, but not with CAC. I receive the error "The remote computer that you are trying to connect to requires NLA, but your Windows domain controller cannot be contacted dot perform NLA. You can try connecting to the remote computer using your username and password instead."

The computer I'm attempting the RDP session from is not on the same domain as the domain controller, if that helps.

Comment: You are sure the AD domain you are attempting to authenticate with, is configured, to authenticate with a Smart Card containing a certificate? The error you received suggests it's not.

Comment: Can your computer *reach* the target's domain controllers? Membership in domain isn't what the message is about, it's about being able to talk to the domain in general.

Comment: I am not entirely sure, how the domain be a different domain, as the domain controller.  Smart Card authentication can most certainly be used to to authenticate an AD domain user on the domain controller itself.  But I am little confused by the fact the session you are trying to initiate, isn't on the domain (but a different domain), as the AD domain controller.

Comment: Yes, I can reach the domain controller. I can log in with username and password. The only time I get the issue is with cac logging directly into servers. The DC is also being used when we authenticate via cac into our F5 webtops.

Comment: Do you mean logging in with username and password to the DC or to the servers?

Comment: Both. I can RDP into both the DC and servers with U/P. Also for more clarification, the RDP session is being created through an F5 webtop tile. These VMs are hosted in Azure and don't have public IPs. The tile in the F5 creates an RDP file which uses the F5 as a gateway to reach the VMs. That's why I can RDP from anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you were still using NTLM for password-based authentication. With NTLM, only the server needs to reach a DC; the client doesn't need anything special. Being able to log in with a password, therefore, does not prove that *you're* able to access a DC; it only proves that the RDP server is able to.

Certificate (smart card) authentication, however, requires Kerberos (it uses PKINIT). With Kerberos it's the opposite – the *client* needs to talk to the KDC in order to acquire a ticket which it will then present to the server.

So by default, clients must be able to reach a DC on port 88 TCP+UDP for Kerberos (and most likely also the dreaded port 389 UDP for CLDAP, for "DC Locator"...), which usually means a VPN.

An alternative is to set up a HTTP Kerberos proxy (per MS-KKDCP); every AD DC can be made to act as a KKDCP server but one can also run a small Python proxy on some Linux box, and on the client side you can specify the proxy URL within the .RDP file. This avoids the requirement to expose any UDP ports.